# The ambiguity of structures like 'ask someone to do something'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

When you, for example, appeal to someone to do something, do I understand correctly that it can both mean that that "something" is what you want them to do **OR** that it is the purpose of your appeal? For example, the sentence

> I appealed to her to get help.

seems to be ambiguous, am I right? Does it mean that you want her to get help or that the purpose of your appeal is to get help (for yourself)? It can mean both, can't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for your example sentence, it is ambiguous, but it wouldn't be with context.

> I appealed to her to get help (for her drug problem).

vs.

> I was pinned under the car, when I saw her legs. I appealed to her to get help (to rescue me).

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd situation (to get help for yourself), you can try
'I appealed to her for help.'